# How can I generate Power Spectra?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have some epidemiological data.  The data is inherently periodic, and so I would like to visualize the power spectra so as to gain insight into the frequency of oscillations.

[image]

The book I am reading outlines a method to visualize the power spectra:

1. De-trend the data
2. Compute the fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of the detrended data.
3. smooth with suitable spectral window such as Tukey WIndow or Bartlett window.

(Book is [Mathematical Epidemiology](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-78911-6), page 311-312).

I was wondering if there is a function in python to do this?  If not, what functions and libraries can I use?

Comment: look into the `scipy` library to find `scipy.fft`

Comment: And for the detrending and smoothing with spectral window?

Comment: numpy has windowing functions to smooth data